# How to clear screen on adb?

Tags: android, adb

In windows cmd, you can type 'cls' to clear the terminal screen.

I have tried cls / clear / reset, and none has cleaned the terminal.

Does adb have any equivalent command or maybe a shortcut?

Comment: that's strange... the command `clear` should be available on adb shell. Are you sure you're using `adb shell clear`?

Answer (score 0):

when on the terminal screen try ctrl+l to clear the whole screen
-or-
type 'adb shell clear' to 'push' all the text up and the first showing line will be c:\etc...

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your version and `clear` is usually available

```
$ which clear
/system/bin/clear
```